# Filtering angular 2 table using an input box

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to filter a table using a pipe.
This is the code of my filter.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myFilter'
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(args[0]) !== -1);
  }
}
```

I imported the filter in my app.module.ts

```js
    import { MyFilterPipe } from './common/my-filter.pipe';
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyFilterPipe
  ],
```

This is my code for the view HTML

```html
<md-input-container>
    <md-icon>search</md-icon>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food"  [(ngModel)]="filterItem">
   </md-input-container> 
... 
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | myFilter: filterItem">
    <td>
      <a  href="#">
         <span >
         {{item.name}}
         </span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>{{item.value1}}</div>
      <div>{{item.value2}}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span >
         item.description
        </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I try to view the page, I have this error in the browser: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined." Because of the filter, the page doesn't want to load. My guess is that since `filterItem` is empty initially, this prevents the page to load. But I don't know how to solve it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `args` is the undefined value here, maybe you could update your filter to only run if `args` is defined as prior that there is no need to run the filter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that since filterItem is empty initially, this prevents
>   the page to load.

In fact it's **undefined**.

The problem can be fixed doing the following:

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
  return !!args ? value.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(args[0]) !== -1) : value;
}
```